# PHP only returns one result from a mysql query - mysql console returns dozens

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to read all the data from my database, when I run this query from the console I get many results but for some reason php is only reading one.

```
$query = "
   SELECT b.raw as 'address', a.raw as 'name', c.TouchTime as 'time'
   FROM touchName a, touchHome b, trackTouch c
   WHERE a.raw like \"%{$name}%\" 
      AND c.AgentID = 1
      AND a.relations = b.relations
      AND b.relations = c.relations
      AND a.relations = c.relations
   ORDER BY time desc
";

//So we can double check in the console
echo $query . "<br><br>";

$result = mysqli_query($mc, $query);

$array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

//says there is only one row
$total = count( mysqli_num_rows($result) );
echo $total."<br>";
```

I have tried many ways of breaking the data out of the result, I have modified the query in several ways, with group by's, counts, etc trying to break this out.

Fairly new to joins also so if this is ugly, it's because it was the first hack that didn't spit out 12 million results.

Comment: You need to fetch the results in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $array[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I was using a for loop comparing `$i` to this flawed code `$total = count( mysqli_num_rows($result) );` which of course will return `1` no matter what. This method removes even the possibility of this error.

Answer (score 0):

The function `mysql_fetch_assoc`  returns a single record by default .
You'll need to iterate loop as @tyralcori said..

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "
   SELECT b.raw as 'address', a.raw as 'name', c.TouchTime as 'time'
   FROM touchName a, touchHome b, trackTouch c
   WHERE a.raw like \"%{$name}%\" 
      AND c.AgentID = 1
      AND a.relations = b.relations
      AND b.relations = c.relations
      AND a.relations = c.relations
   ORDER BY time desc
";

echo $query;
$handler= mysqli_query($mc, $query);
$result = array();  
while($rec = mysqli_fetch_assoc($handler)){
    $result[]['address'] = $rec['address'];
    $result[]['name'] = $rec['name'];
    $result[]['time'] = $rec['time'];
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This is a good piece of code, I would have at least +1 if I could. But I was using a for loop comparing $i to this flawed code $total = count( mysqli_num_rows($result) ); which of course will return 1 no matter what. This method removes even the possibility of this error.